# Comparison of log-likelihood of two non-nested models

Tags: logistic, probit, likelihood, nested-models

I know I can only use the log-likelihoods of two models as selection criterion if they are nested. However, I don't understand this completely. Why isn't it possible to apply this reasoning to non-nested models? I think the higher the log-likelihood the better fits the model the data. I am also aware of other criteria as AIC but this doesn't helps me to understand the issue with the log-likelihoods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* compare the log-likelihoods of two non-nested models. See [Cox (1961), "Tests of separate families of hypotheses"), *Proc. Fourth Berkeley Symp. on Math. Statist. and Prob.*, **1**](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200512162)  & [Cox (1962), "Further results on tests of separate families of hypotheses", *JRSS B*, **24**, 2](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2984232). But the log-likelihood ratio test statistic doesn't have the asymptotic chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the difference in the no. estimated parameters that is so convenient when the models compared are nested. See [Wilks (1938), "The large-sample distribution of the likelihood ratio for testing composite hypotheses", Ann. Math. Statist., **9**, 1](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177732360).

Comment: If it is comparable, what is needed to be sure to conclude one model is superior?

Comment: @Scortchi; The comparability you speak can be intended as follow? if the LLF of model A is greater than one of model B, where the number of parameters of A is equal or lower than B, A is better. This is ok? This my question is related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/546328/distributions-fitting-a-comparison